# Macbook, Can't boot from USB because has no administrator in startup utility

Tags: boot, mac, security, usb-flash-drive, macos-catalina

When I was going to ReInstall a fresh copy of Catalina MacOS on my Macbook pro 2019, unfortunately I deleted all partitions instead of erasing them. As my internet connection is so unstable as much as I repeated installing the OS from the net, it was failing with different errors usually related to the network errors or corrupted raw data.

I created a bootable media flash drive by these steps https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201372.

Now when I want to boot the device from the USB drive,
[image]

it says "Security settings do not allow this Mac to use an external startup disk".
[image]

I waned to allow my Mac booting from external media (as this link https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT208198) but It shows me the error: "Authentication Needed - You will need to authenticate as an Administrator to change the boot security settings."

[image]

And when I click on Enter macOS Password I see this error : "Recovery is trying to change system settings. No administrator was found."

[image]

I had never set a password for my mac bios and also I've removed my Macbook from my apple account too.

I've searched a lot and watched lots of youtube videos but didn't succeed anything yet. How can I fix my issue to allow me boot from the flash drive?

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: @bbqchickenrobot Yes, I backed up whole of a working Macbook disk by disk utility to an external hard drive and restored it to this macbook. a painful process, but fortunately solved the issue.

Comment: @AhmadBehzadi How did you achieve this with no administrator and no way of setting a startup disk? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: @Petruza I backed up from another Macbook disk to an external hard drive. Then I connected the USB drive to the damaged Macbook. Then I used disk utility to restore from external drive to local disk drive. It created a full copy from that Macbook. So I could use the administrator user that was working in the healthy Macbook

Comment: @AhmadBehzadi ok, I learned a lot since this post, and the problem is I have a working mac with High Sierra, which is the latest it supports. I would need to do a backup of a Catalina install to be able to restore it on the new MBP.
But if I had a Mac with Catalina I would use Apple Configurator which is better.